# Spree not allowing me to add new routes/models into backedn admin functionality of the app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, spree

I am new to spree , I want to add new model at admin side , I followed the one article to add new models but getting error  uninitialized constant Spree::ThemeSupport .

And also I decided to override views and added new routes into my app but my newly added routes are not detecting by spree . I am getting another error "NameError in Spree::Admin::Products#edit"

Is there any perfect tutorial that we can follow to customize spree admin backend .

Thanks ,

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to add new model to the admin(backend). Create a new model in **spree/core** folder like in your case its **spree/core/theme_support.rb**

```
module Spree
  class ThemeSupport < Spree::Base
    " Your code"
  end
end
```

And for overriding the views [Spree Docs](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/view.html). Use have to use the [deface gem](https://github.com/spree/deface) for override.

Comment: ThemeSupport is not my own class , I followed the following arcticle , after I did all I got that error .

http://quickleft.com/blog/how-to-add-a-custom-model-to-your-spree-app

Comment: It's a very old documentation, what exactly you wanted to implement in you app?

Comment: Hey thanks for letting me know . I want to add new model call items in relation with products just like what we see images for products in admin panel , so where do i need to create models,controller,routes(pls tell me with any namespace). if you have reference links please provide me I need it .

Comment: I have done in one of my project in Spree, you can take that reference if its helpful if in case you gets any doubt just let me know https://github.com/bigstores/spree/commit/f43091e834ea273004decc6ebf29d648374f6853